# how do i set the onclick() property of a button in an ejs file

Tags: javascript, ejs, browserify

I want one of the buttons in my .ejs file to call a function to be executed from an external javascript file. The button needs to send the radio-button value for processing that external javascript file.

This is a part of the .ejs file:

```
<form>
    <div class="radio">
        <h3><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="option 1">option 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <h3><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="option 2">option 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="radio ">
        <h3><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="option 3">option 3</h3>
    </div>

    <br>

    <a href="/identity"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
            id="submit">Submit</button> </a>

    <a href="/verify"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="verify">Verify </button> </a>

</form>
```

I do not want to add the javascript code in the script tags because the javascript file the function is being passed to is a browserify bundle.js file.

Comment: Are you including the "bundle.js" on the page?

Comment: @Olian04 yes, it's in the header. In the script tag